# Using a Selenium function in an Python / SST automation script

Tags: python, selenium

Any senior automation guys out there?  I am writing an automation script using Python with SST and I am running into some limitations with SST.  I would like to borrow a function from the standard Selenium library to use in my script in which I double click a line of text to highlight it.  I create one instance of webdriver in the beginning of the script with SST and begin performing actions on a web page.  My question is: is there any way I can share that instance with a Selenium function to perform this one action.  I realize I could do the entire script in Selenium but the company I work for is committed to SST and that would not be accepted.  I do not think anyone would mind if I threw one Selenium function in though.  Since SST is built on Selenium, I figured there must be a new class that has been written which I can import to perform an action such as this.  The code I would like to execute would look something like the following.  But of course when I create the second instance of webdriver with Selenium, a new browser is opened and the scripts are then logically split in half.  Any tips?

```
from sst.actions import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import *

go_to('http:/yadayada.net/')
## perform a bunch of actions
text = ## get text element with SST

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.double_click(text)
action.perform()
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the underlying webdriver, you want to reference:

```
sst.actions._test.browser
```

Here is an example of an [SST](http://testutils.org/sst/) script that uses the `webdriver.Firefox` instance directly:

```
import sst.actions

# a regular SST action
sst.actions.go_to('http:/testutils.org/sst')

# now using webdriver directly 
sst.actions._test.browser.get('http://www.python.org')
```

The example in your question could be written as:

```
from sst.actions import *
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains

go_to('http:/yadayada.net/')
## perform a bunch of actions
text = ## get text element with SST

driver = sst.actions._test.browser
action = action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.double_click(text)
action.perform()
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and got the error below.  Not sure why it is not recognizing the class that I already referenced earlier in the code. I don't doubt it worked on your end, we may may just have some version descrepancy:

Comment: Please refer to my answer to the question. Thanks for your input, Corey.                                                       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    driver = sst.actions._test.browser
NameError: name 'sst' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I though I had it figured out, which was create instance with SST (i.e. page = start('Firefox')), then reference that later in the code (i.e. driver = webdriver.page()). Neither way worked though. Not really convinced Selenium and SST can share an instance of webdriver since I cannot find any documentation saying so. So, still looking, thanks.

Comment: @Daemon, try the exact code in the first snippet of my answer.  Also remember it is an sst "script", and must be run via 'sst-run', not directly in a python interpreter.

Comment: @Daemon, if you are still running into problems, also verify you are an the latest SST release (currently 0.2.4)

Comment: I created a .py file in a text editor and ran that snippet from command prompt and received:                                 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\delete.py", line 3, in <module>
    sst.actions._test.browser.get('http://www.python.org')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'browser'

Comment: We run all of our test scripts from an IDE anyway so I cannot use it if it doesn't work in that environment. It doesn't seem that Selenium functions will execute unless you actually create a webdriver instance using the Selenium syntax (driver = webdriver.Firefox()). What I am trying to do is execute Selenium functions within the same webdriver instance (web page) that I created with SST, or vice versa. Are you sure this is possible?

Comment: Also, my SST version is up to date.  Thanks.

Comment: @Daemon, i'm positive it is possible.  and I have showed you example code.  I don't know what your IDE setup involves, but you can not just "create a .py file in a text editor and ran that snippet from command prompt".  to invoke an SST script named delete.py, you would run `$ sst-run delete`.  see: http://testutils.org/sst/#running-a-test-with-sst

Comment: I appreciate you following up. I'll spend a bit more time at the office tomorrow getting the results I need from command line.  If that works I will try to reconfigure my IDE to get the same results from that environment. But if it's a case of having to reconfigure the IDE of anyone running the script, I will have to drop it.  I will post an update tomorrow though regardless. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: You were correct, my friend. I assumed my SST version was current but it was not. You cannot invoke _test.browser on 2.2. I updated and your code worked, but then the rest of my old code broke and I had to revert to 2.2. I appreciate your help and look forward to using this method when I can get the rest of the company on board. I also found some info from your update below.  Thanks again.   https://code.launchpad.net/~vila/selenium-simple-test/1161336-hookable-browser/+merge/158395